# Pausing function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function which loops through rows in a table so that only one is shown at any given time.

I want to expand on this so that when I hover over the table, it shows all the rows, and then when I move away, it resumes showing one row at a time.

The Problem I have is that on hovering, the first function keeps going, is there a way to 'pause' the function. I've looked at various examples using ClearInterval(),but can't match them to my script.

```
//Calling The function that loops through the rows    
function hideShow(time)
{   
    setInterval('showRows()',time); 
};      

//Set the time between each 'loop' and start looping 
$(document).ready(function()
{
    hideShow(2000);
}   
);

//The hover function to show / hide all the rows
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#dbTable1 tr').hover(function() 
        {
            $('.Group td').removeClass('RoundBottom');
            $('.Group').show();
        },  
        function()
        {
            $('.Group td').addClass('RoundBottom');
            $('.Group').hide();
        }
    ); 
}
);
```

Can anyone show me please how I can combine the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the timer ID when you call `setInterval`:

```
var timerID;

function hideShow(time){
  timerID = setInterval(showRows, time);
}
```

Then later on when you want to stop the repetition, call `clearInterval` and pass in that ID:

```
// ...
  $('.Group td').removeClass('RoundBottom');
  $('.Group').show();
  clearInterval(timerID);
},
function()
{
  hideShow(2000);
  $('.Group td').addClass('RoundBottom');
  // ...
```

Comment: Cheers, I was so close, but not quite there. That works great.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check the hovering state before doing anything else, like this:

```
function showRows() {
    if (isHovering) {
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The `isHovering` variable is just a boolean with current hovering state, that could be set by your callback function.

With the above approach, you can set your timer only once and forget about it.